# Crash while getting value from the dictionary in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, nsdictionary, nsmutabledictionary

I have created a dictionary like

```
var tempArray1 = ["sdds","dsads"]
var tempArray2: AnyObject = ["sddsa",34,tempArray1]
var dictionary: [String:Array] = ["key1":["value1"],"key2":["value2",6,tempArray2]]
```

The application crashed when I tried to print all values from the dictionary like

```
let allValues = [Array](dictionary.values)
for value in allValues{
     println(value)
}
```

I just started learning dictionary concept in swift language. I want to know my approach is right or wrong.
Please help me to figure it out

Comment: any error or exception message?

Comment: "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" - error messsage.

Comment: you have optional vars which are nil, can you show further code?

Comment: The above mentioned is the only code I have written in viewdidload

Comment: When i tried by using key. It is working fine, let allKeys = [String] (dict. keys)
        for key in allKeys{
            println(dict[key])
        } and count for values is 140380082480672

Comment: Not an `if let` in sight. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Swift arrays have associated I don't think that you can declare type with array without specifying its associated type. I am not sure why you do not get compile time errors. This should work:

```
var tempArray1 = ["sdds","dsads"]
var tempArray2: AnyObject = ["sddsa",34,tempArray1]
var dictionary: [String:Array<AnyObject>] = ["key1":["value1"],"key2":["value2",6,tempArray2]]

let allValues = [Array<AnyObject>](dictionary.values)
for value in allValues{
    println(value)
}
```

Or even shorter:

```
var tempArray1 = ["sdds","dsads"]
var tempArray2: AnyObject = ["sddsa",34,tempArray1]
var dictionary: [String:[AnyObject]] = ["key1":["value1"],"key2":["value2",6,tempArray2]]

let allValues = dictionary.values
for value in allValues{
    println(value)
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :). Finally, I should mention which type of array it is. (Array<AnyObject). So,  we cannot set object as an array without datatype in the dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this also

```
var tempArray1 = ["sdds","dsads"]  
var tempArray2: AnyObject = ["sddsa",34,tempArray1]

println("Array inside array \(tempArray2)")
    var dictionary: [String:Array] = ["key1":["value1"],"key2":["value2",6,tempArray2]]

    println(dictionary)

    let allValues = Array(dictionary.values)
    for value in allValues{
        println(value)
    }
```